# Adding a formula to blank cells within a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

```
 function copyformula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formrange = ss.getRange("J1");
  var formval = formrange.getValues();
  var sourceSheets = ss.getSheets();
  for( sheetNumber = 2; sheetNumber < sourceSheets.length; sheetNumber++) {
  var range = ss.getRange("J3:J1000");
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == '') {
      var cell = range.offset(i, 0, 1, 1);   
      cell.setValues(formval);
      Utilities.sleep(750); //Edit value to adjust amount of pause between function calls (time is in milliseconds). Make it long enough to avoid #error, but not too long to save time.

    }
  }
} 
}
```

Hi so the aim is, to check for blank cells in column J3:J1000, (It will need to look through multiple sheets) If there is a blank cell, replace it with the formula in J1 (This will be on all sheets). I need it to copy the formula which is in J1 and paste it, so it changes all the cell references. Example: Lets say J307 is empty, the formula is copied from J1 and is pasted in J307, but all the If's etc are now based on J307 and other cells values around it. This will be set up to work with google triggers (on change)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :). At the moment the script above is not doing anything and times out.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. In your script, `ss.getRange("J1")` is the cell "J1" in the 1st tab. You want to use the formula of this cell? 2. You want to copy the formula of cell "J1" in the 1st tab to the empty cells in the column "J" of all sheets except for 1st tab. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi Tanaike :)

1) J1 cell is in every sheet tab. 
2) I want to use the formula which is currently in there, to be copied and pasted between cells J3 and J1000 if they are blank. (some will be blank, some won't be). The trick is though, that copied formula in J1 needs to change to the values off for example J307, so all the IF's etc will use "If J307..." So on and so fourth.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so, it only does the check on which ever sheet the edit was initially made on? rather than having to go through all the sheets? and wasting time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal. Which sheet do you want to check it? For example, you will use the sheet name?

Comment: I have multiple sheets, each day more are added. So it needs to look through all sheetnumbers >2, Can't use a specific sheet name, or I would need to change the name everyday. I don't want to do that.

Comment: Tanaike, will it be easier if i created a test document so you have a better understanding?

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you provided it, I think that it will help to understand your situation.

Comment: Thank you for it. But unfortunately, I cannot read it. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could read it. I have one more question. In your situation, it is required to check `J3:J1000`? For example, how about checking from `J3` to the last row of the data range?

Comment: That would be more efficient. Yes :) Because it is possible that sometimes might be required to go over 1000 lines.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the formula from the cell "J1" on each sheet to the empty cells of the column "J".
- You want to reflect the row number to the formula when the formula is put to the cell.
- You want to check the sheet index from 2 to last index.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

```
function copyformula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheets = ss.getSheets();
  for( sheetNumber = 2; sheetNumber < sourceSheets.length; sheetNumber++) {
    var sheet = sourceSheets[sheetNumber];
    var values = sheet.getRange("J3:J" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();  // Modified
    var formula = sheet.getRange("J1");
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {  // Modified
      if (!values[i][0]) {  // Modified
        formula.copyTo(sheet.getRange(`J${i + 3}`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- In order to reflect the row number to the copied formula, I used `copyTo`.
- In this case, the row 3 to the last row of the data range are checked.
- If you don't want to use V8, please modify `` sheet.getRange(`J${i + 3}`) `` to `sheet.getRange("J" + (i + 3))`.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

Comment: Tanaike, it seems to be overwriting even values which are not blank :/

Comment: Its putting formulas in every cell, and not just blank ones :/

Comment: @Falcon Thank you for replying. From your replying, the values are checked instead of the formulas. So I updated the script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Perfect :) Can you explain to me how this script is working so quickly?

I am using a similar script to copy values and paste it, and its so slow!

Comment: @Falcon Thank you for replying. I think that it might be the difference of the cost between `setValue` and `copyTo`. By the way, I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Falcon Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. If this answer couldn't directly resolve your new question, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, it will help a lot of users including me think of your new question. How about this?

Comment: I have posted a new question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585691/converting-values-given-by-formulas-into-hard-cell-values-over-multiple-sheets